# Android widget displaying temperature in both Fahrenheit and Celsius

Tags: android, weather

Is there a weather widget for android phones capable of displaying the current temperature both in Fahrenheit and Celsius  *at the same time*? That is, I'm not looking for widgets like the one shipped with the HTC one, the AccuWeather app etc. which only seem able to display the temperature in one scale at a time.

Edit 2014:
I currently run Android 4.4.2, so that'd be a good cut-off. It doesn't have to be fancy. Ideally, it'd be like the HTC One (M7) widget which shows the time, a symbol for the current weather and the temperature. The app is preferably free, but I would consider a budget up to $10 (especially if there are other interesting features).

Edit 2022:
Since it appears the "Weather Notification" app by Denis Nelubin is no longer available on Google Play, alternatives for more recent versions of Android (say 10 and above) meeting the same qualifications would be very welcome.

Comment: Is "Weather Notification" app by Denis Nelubin still available? I can't find it in Google Play. I am also looking for a weather app that will show Fahrenheit and Celsius together. I just moved from a Fahrenheit country to a Celsius country and I figured this would be a good way for me to get used to Celsius. Thanks.

Comment: @UStoUK I still have it installed, but it does not appear to be available in Google Play anymore (although other items from Nelubin are). If you're interested, I found an APK at [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/ru.gelin.android.weather.notification/) and the source at [GitHub](https://github.com/gelin/weather-notification). Obviously, it'd be ideal if there was a new alternative available on Google Play, since many would be more comfortable installing apps from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it in the "Weather Notification" app by "Denis Nelubin". You have to tap in the configuration of the Skin and choose "Celsius(Farenheit)" or vice-versa to show both.

[Weather Notification](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.gelin.android.weather.notification)

Comment: Would you look at [that](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.gelin.android.weather.notification)! I actually did try this app based on the previous answer, but I guess I didn't know where to look for the settings. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Weather notification is the name of one program that shows dual units, but it is not a screen saver type app. So when you want to use it you have to tap the program icon. However, the choices are there, and it even allows you to use C or F first followed by the other, or to choose either one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you have a link to it? I tried out a couple apps called "Weather notification" (and even "Notification weather") I found on Google Play, but I did not find the options you mention.